# Help solving the integral: $\int_{-\varphi_\beta}^{2\pi-\varphi_\beta}\sqrt{2-b\cos x}\,dx \\ $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate a definite integral of:

$$\int_{-\varphi_\beta}^{2\pi-\varphi_\beta}\sqrt{2-b\cos x}\,dx,\quad 0\leq b\leq 1.$$

To be more precise I am  trying to find a double definite integral of:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{p_\alpha(1-p_\alpha)}\cos (\varphi_\alpha-\varphi_\beta)}\,d\varphi_\alpha\,d\varphi_\beta,\quad 0\leq p\leq 1.$$

But I guess one needs to begin with the first form anyway :(

Thank you all for your helpful comments.

And I apologize everyone for the mistake that I made in my original question. Since my ultimate goal is to calculate the double definite integral above, the limits of the first integral are not from $ 0 $ to $ 2\pi $ but from $ -\varphi_\beta $ to $ 2\pi-\varphi_\beta $. So the first integral in question has a form
$
\int_{-\varphi_\beta}^{2\pi-\varphi_\beta}\sqrt{2-b\cos x}\,dx,\quad 0\leq b\leq 1.
$
I may not take an advantage of the symmetry then.

Comment: I think because no closed form in terms of elemantary functions exists.

Answer (score 5):

You may consider that
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{2-b\cos x}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{2-b\cos x}\,dx = 4\sqrt{2+b}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac{2b}{2+b}\cos^2 x}\,dx.\tag{1}$$
Since 
$$ \sqrt{1-z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{(1-2n)4^n} z^n \tag{2} $$
for any $z\in(-1,1)$, and
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n} \tag{3} $$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the original integral can be written as
$$ 2\pi\sqrt{2+b}\,\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2}{(1-2n)16^n}\left(\frac{2b}{2+b}\right)^n = 4\sqrt{2+b}\,E\left(\frac{2b}{2+b}\right)\approx 2\pi \sqrt{2}-\frac{\pi  b^2}{16 \sqrt{2}}\tag{4} $$
where $E$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) (related to the perimeter of the ellipse) and the argument of $E$ is the elliptic modulus as in Mathematica's notation. In the section of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) about elliptic integrals you may find some interesting algebraic approximations, not including [Ramanujan's one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2120536_Ramanujan%27s_Perimeter_of_an_Ellipse). $E(x)$ can be computed through numerical algorithms with quadratic convergence (like Newton's method) and it has a very nice [Fourier-Legendre expansion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03221):
$$E(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4 P_n(2x-1)}{(1-2n)(2n+1)(2n+3)}\tag{5} $$
but it is not considered an *elementary* function, at least usually.

Comment: Thank you for the symmetry hint (2*(0, pi)). I haven't noticed it.

Comment: @Szymon: you're welcome. For practical (physical, I guess) purposes the approximation appearing in the RHS of $(4)$ should be accurate enough.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Dev Platform yields, from the command `Integrate[Sqrt[2-b Cos[x]],{x,0,2 Pi}]`, the result
$$\operatorname{ConditionalExpression}\left[2\left(\sqrt{2-b}\,\operatorname{EllipticE}\left[\frac{2b}{b-2}\right]+\sqrt{2+b}\,\operatorname{EllipticE}\left[\frac{2b}{2+b}\right]\right),-2<\operatorname{Re}[b]<2\right]. $$ 
The `EllipticE` function is defined by 
$$\operatorname{EllipticE}[x]=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-x \sin^2(\theta)}\,d\theta.$$
While this doesn't help you much, it does show that you're not likely to get a closed-form expression in terms of elementary antiderivatives.

Also, as an aside: MATLAB is terrific for numerics, but don't expect its symbolic toolbox ever to match Mathematica/Wolfram Language.

Comment: By the way, it seems that all of the above is just $4 \sqrt{2-b} E\left(\frac{2 b}{b-2}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the answers, you can have quite good approximations using Padé approximants.

For the same degree in numerator and denominator, here are some
$$\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \pi -\frac{19 \pi }{64 \sqrt{2}} b^2 } {1-\frac{15 }{256} b^2 } $$
$$\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \pi -\frac{633 \pi  }{832 \sqrt{2}} b^2+\frac{4799 \pi  }{212992
   \sqrt{2}}b^4 } {1-\frac{581 }{3328}b^2+\frac{3255 }{851968}b^4 }$$

These are equivalent to Taylor expansions $O(b^6)$ and $O(b^{10})$

**Update**

If we consider
$$I=\int_{-a}^{2\pi-a}\sqrt{2-b\cos x}\,dx $$ a CAS provides
$$I=2 \sqrt{2-b} \left(E\left(\frac{a}{2}|\frac{2 b}{b-2}\right)+E\left(\frac{2
   \pi -a}{2} |\frac{2 b}{b-2}\right)\right)$$ but
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}=0$$ taking us back to the original question where $a=0$.

Comment: Thank you. That is promising indeed. I'll get into your proposition and let you know the results.

Comment: @Szymon. You are welcome ! Do I need to confess that I enjoy Padé approximants ?

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide me with a Padé approximant of sqrt(2-b*cos(x)) instead of the integral itself. Unfortunately my version of Matlab does not have symbolic Padé approximation (and I was unable to find any online service of this kind) :(

Comment: @Szymon. This would not be good at all ! You must integrate first and the approximate the result as a Padé approximant. In any manner, I can provide you the one you would like to have.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in solving this integral.